# Review test catching people indiscriminately for duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, review-audits

I occasionally get flagged for not passing a review audit test because of duplicate questions.

In nearly all cases for a duplicate answer vote the easiest way to see the candidate questions is to choose "Close" button, then click "Duplicate of...", then it will show you the question previous people think is the duplicate. If I read it and I do not think it is a duplicate, I hit the "X" button in the upper right to cancel the operation and go back to the question. If I do think it is a duplicate, I click the "Vote to Close" button.

The problem is that the current auditing system thinks you are voting to close as soon as you click the first "Close" button (which is not true), thus you get falsely criticized by the system for trying to make an invalid close when all you were trying to do was see the duplicate question.

I would suggest fixing this by making the audit only complete when the person clicks the "Vote to Close" button, not when they click the "Close" button.

Comment: Also related: [Delay judgment on close votes review audits until "Vote To Close" is clicked in lightbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211978/delay-judgment-on-close-votes-review-audits-until-vote-to-close-is-clicked-in?rq=1)

Comment: Noticing that the other question has be there for almost a year, why is this problem still existing?

Comment: @TylerDurden it's still being rewritten, I guess

Comment: You do realize that you could just [click the "Duplicate" tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8lVpl.png), right?